# Finding the distribution of a random variable knowing the distribution of its transformation

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose $x$ is a non-negative random variable with CDF denoted $F$ and let $v = x+e^{-(x+1-\alpha)}$ for some $\alpha\geq 0$. Finally, let $G(v)=1-e^{-(v-\alpha)}$.

Is there a $F$ and $\alpha$ such that the CDF of $v$ is equal to $G(v)=1-e^{(v-\alpha)}$ for $v \in [\alpha,\infty)$?

More generally, if a know $v\sim G $ and $v=T(x)$ for some random variable $x \sim F$, is there a method to find $F$?

Comment: Certainly not a general method. Sometimes from $v=T(x)$ you can find an expression for $x$ in $v$ and go on from there, but for that $T$ must be at least be injective.